# are default constructors for struct called just like class in C++

Tags: c++

Do C++ struct also call constructors (default, copy constructors) and destructors just like classes or they follow the C language guidelines for struct? So in the example below, is a default constructor called?

```
Foo structObject; \\Foo is a struct
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they do. The **only** difference between `struct` and `class` in C++ is in visibility of it's members. `Struct` has by-default members public, `class` private.

Effectively, writing

```
class A {
public:
//// ...
}
```

is the same as writing

```
struct A {
//// ...
}
```

Comment: Also, default access specifier for inheritance (if a `struct` inherits from something, the inheritance is `public` by default, while for `class` it's `private`).

Comment: How does the struct construction in C++ and in C differ?

Comment: @vkaul11 structs in C cannot have member functions, and by extension, constructors